# youtube api v3 user per limit by send ip user to youtube

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

i am use php youtube v3 every time send server ip to youtube api
and api limit per user  3000

so i want to send ip to youtube api for per limition error remove

How can i send user ip php youtube v3 to youtube api

Answer (score 0):

To link a request to a specific user, so the per-user limit can be used - you need to include either of the `quotaUser` or `userIp` standard query parameters.

See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/standard_parameters